# Why happen Class 'net.sf.json.spring.web.servlet.view.JsonView' not found?

Tags: json, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I made the following settings to use jsonView.

dispatcher-serlvet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<bean id="jsonView" class="net.sf.json.spring.web.servlet.view.JsonView"> 
            <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" /> 
        </bean> 
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

However, the following error occurs in dispatcher-sevlet.xml:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Class 'net.sf.json.spring.web.servlet.view.JsonView' not found
- Class 'net.sf.json.spring.web.servlet.view.JsonView' not found [config set: rachelivf/web-
 context]
```

I don t know why this is happening. Beginners need answers. Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue.

The content I wrote for the dispacther-servlet was old.

The code has been modified to read(dispacther-serlvet.xml):

```
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

As a result, the error is gone.